# How to get better Plots.jl xaxis tick labels with Time data in Julia?

Tags: plot, time, julia, visualization, plots.jl

I would like to see `[00:00:00, 02:00:00, 04:00:00, 06:00:00]` or similar as the xtick labels. The pyplot and GR backends gave similar results. I am fine using any backend that supports both a left and right yaxis.

#### Default Plot

```
using DataFrames, Dates, Plots
gr(linewidth=3, markersize=4, titlefont=18, legendfont=12, guidefont=18, tickfont=14, legend=:outertopright)
df = DataFrame()
df.Time = ["0:05:02", "1:05:23", "2:05:34", "4:05:42", "5:36:01"]
df.Data = [0.0, 1.0, 0.5, 0.4, 0.1]
df.Time = Time.(df.Time, DateFormat("H:M:S"))
plot(df.Time, df.Data)
```

[image: default.png]

#### My Attempts

```
julia> plot(df.Time, df.Data, lims = :round)
```

[image: lims.png]

```
julia> plot(df.Time, df.Data, ticks = 4)
```

[image: ticks.png]

```
julia> plot(df.Time, df.Data, lims = :round, ticks = 4)
```

[image: lims_ticks.png]

```
julia> plot(df.Time, df.Data, xlims = (Time(0), Time(6)))
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching Float64(::Time)
Closest candidates are:
  Float64(::UInt32) at float.jl:66
  Float64(::Int128) at float.jl:94
  Float64(::Float16) at float.jl:256
  ...
Stacktrace:
 [1] (::RecipesPipeline.var"#7#8"{Symbol})(::Time) at C:\Users\nboyer.AIP\.julia\packages\RecipesPipeline\uPBKQ\src\utils.jl:201
 [2] optimal_ticks_and_labels(::Plots.Subplot{Plots.GRBackend}, ::Plots.Axis, ::Nothing) at C:\Users\nboyer.AIP\.julia\packages\Plots\vsE7b\src\axes.jl:167
```

```
julia> plot(df.Time, df.Data, xticks = Time(0):Hour(2):Time(6))
```

[image: xticks.png]

The last attempt setting `xticks` is close, but I still can't get the last tick to appear. Interestingly, it doesn't matter what I set the last value of the range to be. `xticks = Time(0):Hour(2):Time(10)` produces the same image.

Comment: did you try `xticks = Time(0):Hour(2):Time(6)` ? (`Hour` is a duration)

Comment: or `xlims = (Time(0), Time(6))`

Comment: @MarcMush Thanks for the tips! I updated the question to incorporate your suggestions. The `xticks` option is probably good enough, but I will leave the question open to see if there is anything better.

Comment: After further investigation, the `xticks` solution will not change how the graph looks in any way, only the axis. `Time(6)` doesn't appear because it is off the chart. Likewise, if I use `xticks = Time(2):Hour(2):Time(4)`, the only effect is removing the `00:00:00` tick label. I would prefer a method which also rescales the graph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work :

```
plot(df.Time, df.Data, 
     xlims = (Dates.value(Time(0)), Dates.value(Time(6))), 
     xticks = Time(0):Hour(2):Time(6)
)
```

I feel this should be possible without `Dates.value`.

Very recently, support was added for `Date` and `DateTime` (https://github.com/JuliaPlots/Plots.jl/pull/3180), but not `Time` or `TimePeriod`